# Drag and drop images from desktop to WYSIWYG editor

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, editor

In Google Docs it is possible to drag and drop images from your desktop to a document.

Does there exist an open source application (such as CKEditor, tinymce) that also supports this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Aloha Editor has some experimental plugins which show the possibilities. Those are not yet production ready.

A working example at http://labs.tapo-it.com/aloha/aloha-imageplugin/examples/example.html

There is another plugin which is still in heavy development bringing a more generic functionality to Aloha Editor. http://www.aloha-editor.com/wiki/index.php/Drag%26DropFiles